# How to login to a site with Java

Tags: java, passwords, web-crawler

I need to login to a home page, but I want my program to do it, or somehow the when I logged in through a browser, my program have access to the web pages.

The form is like this:

```
<form name="something" action="loginchk.asp" method="post" >
```

The source of the login webpage is something like this: (the password field)

```
    <td nowrap>Password:</td>

    <td>      <input type="password" name="pass" value="" document.scopeeslogin.splctl.value='1';" onselect="storeCaret(this);" onclick="storeCaret(this);" onkeyup="storeCaret(this);">

      </td>
```

and the sign in button:

```
< input type="image" src="images/btn_login.gif" alt="Login" onClick="javascript:return Validate();"  />
```

and the Validate function:

```
function Validate()
{ 
     if (document.scopeeslogin.pass.value=='')
     {

    alert('Please enter password');
    document.scopeeslogin.pass.focus();
    return false;
     }
     return true;
```

}

Comment: Why can't you send the password as part of the get request? Also, you might want to look into [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_client.html).

Comment: I tried it doesn't work! I don't know what do u mean by this Selenium link!

Comment: Login in your case involves `javascript` which your java code will not be able to do. So, take a look at any headless browser like `htmlunit` to handle javascript.

Comment: @Chris: I use the get method to call the login page, and the username and other fields are set automatically  But I need to enter the password and click on login, which I don't know how to do by my program

Comment: @AfshinMoazami: you will not be able to do that directly from your java code. Your code cannot magically process/execute javascript.

Comment: Try using `Rhino from Mozilla` and using its integration libraries or maybe using the JDK 1.6 ScriptEngine facility. I have not worked with any of them but it seems `rhino` or `htmlunit` will do the job. I would prefer `htmlunit`.

Comment: @RanRag: thanks! the html unit was really good :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at Selenium.
You can use Java to control your browser to fill out input fields, trigger events and submit forms, also read the resuling page DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if the site is secured by https, you could look into Wireshark and log in with a real browser to look at the http request and formulate a pseudo request with the necessary post information. If it is secured, you'll have to use a javascript execution library.